# Can't Add QuickTime Movie View to Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to add a QuickTime Movie View object to my application but I can't find it in the object library in interface builder. I added the QTKit framework to my project and I'm using XCode 5 and 10.8 as the target. I am following Apple's [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH3-SW8).

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: That's probably because QTKit has been deprecated with XCode5.  Use the AV thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTMovieView` is a subclass of `NSView`.
Simply use a custom view and set it's class to `QTMovieView`.

However I highly advise you to move away from `QTKit`, since it looks like Apple is doing the same thing. You can use [AV Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) instead.